# How to use filter in controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have given code in my function.

```
 $scope.FilteredList = $filter('filter')(ProductService.Products, $scope.FilterExpr, false);
```

where `$scope.FilterExpr` is bind with text field.

Above filter works as expected for me, and when user types something in text field, `$scope.FilteredList` gets populated with filtered items.

`ProductService.Products` is an array of objects with following fields in object. `name`, `mrp`, `sp`, `incart`.

I want to create another filter which filters all the items where `incart` value is > 0.

what should i use instead of `?????` in below line.

```
  $scope.FilteredList = $filter('filter')(ProductService.Products, ?????, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `$filter` again. Do use `.filter` over `$scope.FilteredList` collection to get desired result.

```
var result = $scope.FilteredList.filter(function(item){
   return item.incart > 0;
});
```